# Select Query Similar rank

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `cms_goods`
WHERE rank < 20
     OR rank > 20
LIMIT 10
```

This code returns only return 10 records of rank field less than 20. I want a query to show both less than and greater than records. (Limit 10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a UNION ALL

```
(SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE rank < 20 LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE rank > 20 LIMIT 5)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try a union:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE 
rank < 20 LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE 
rank > 20 LIMIT 5
```

Comment: No - parentheses are not required.

Comment: Change your `LIMIT`s to 5 each; OP wants only 10 total. `UNION ALL` will be faster here.

Comment: Indeed union all will be faster since the result sets are guaranteed to not overlap.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk , it's not going to be a real performance difference with `LIMIT 5`. With `LIMIT 500`, yeah, it would.

Comment: @ypercube It still has to take an extra step for the comparison, does it not?

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk Yes but sorting 10 vs 1000 rows is not the same - regarding efficiency.

Comment: @ypercube I see it as an extra step saved.

Answer (score 2):

the best way was to go through a sub query that would have saved a few mili seconds, but unfortunately mySQL doesn't yet support LIMIT feature in sub queries.

so you best option is to use a union like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE 
rank < 20 LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE 
rank > 20 LIMIT 5
```

e.g:

```
$query = mysq_query("SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE rank < 20 LIMIT 5 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM `cms_goods` WHERE rank > 20 LIMIT 5");
```

Explanation: 
the first query will get 5 top results
the last query will get bottom 5 results
and than UNION ALL will join them in a single result.

P.S: don't forget to mark a comment as answer, whichever helps.

Comment: You give more details than the others, but your queries are identical to the two above you; why re-iterate what has already been done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
LIMIT 10, 20
```

It will select from 10th row and 20 rows next

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries maybe?

```
SELECT * FROM cms_goods WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM cms_goods WHERE rank < 20 LIMIT 10) OR id IN (SELECT id FROM cms_goods where rank > 20 LIMIT 10)
```